# Visual Studio(2017) Tools for Apache Cordova has an error after upgrading to XCode 9

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

Before when I had xcode 8.3 I was able to do a build but when I tried upload the ipa file using application loader it complained that I had to do a build using a higher sdk version(I wasn't able to screenshot the exact error).
After I upgraded to XCode 9 I can no longer do a build because it's now generating an error.

```
Code Signing Error Provisioning profile "XXXXX" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: XXXX (XXXXX)".
Code Signing Error Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
```

No matter what combination I put in the build.json file I keep getting errors relating to provisioning profiles. Has anyone came across this issue? I was also hoping that VSTAC would get an update since it's been quite some time since they updated(or have they stopped development?).

Answer (score 0):

**The second you update Xcode, the remoteagent won't work anymore with VS2017.** You must manually open the .xcworkspace file in Xcode to select a Development Team, and make sure to **automatically manage signing** no matter what.

The only solution I found to keep using Visual Studio, is to [follow these instructions](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/) in order to create a mirrored copy of the project in the Mac. This way you can use a newer Cordova version, and latest Xcode version, and everything will work perfectly fine. Forget about building, deploying and debugging your iOS app from Visual Studio for Windows, and switch to the Mac for these tasks.